# How to deal with employers who send tasks and then don't contact you back?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Recently, I applied for a job through Stack Overflow Jobs, and I don't want to disclose who they were out of fear, but one them had me do a good deal of work (it was about two days full time) and because I am looking for visa sponsorship jobs (which was the case), I did it - the job seemed to be a perfect fit for me.

I believe that I completed the tasks very well and I put a lot of effort into them.

It seems to me that they're just looking for someone who does their job for free...

I wish there was some way to avoid this, but I can't think of anything at the moment.

How do you go about this? I kind of feel bad, not because they never contacted me back, but because I worked for free: I could have spent that time freelancing somewhere else or putting my time to better use.

**Is there a way to report this employer?** Or at least have him put under inspection?

Comment: You think that the task they asked of you was a real thing they needed and not just an example task?

Comment: Surely those tasks must have taken place outside the `jobs`/`careers` communication system - do you not have the means to contact them to follow up?

Comment: I didn't see anything in your Careers message history. Is this something that happened outside of Careers? If you're uncomfortable with publicly naming the company, please let us know at careers@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Your comment needs to be part of your answer @juice, along with a description of whether SE finds this sort of behaviour acceptable, whether or not it happened.

Comment: Shouldn't the question title say "employers" instead of "job seekers"? The title sounds like the OP sent a task to an employer instead of the other way around.

Comment: Seem pretty unlikely given the time span.  Are you sure that this *job* wasn't just a test they use to filter candidates?   I always used them, cuts down on the travel expenses and interview time and whatnot.  In which case you can assume you won't hear back, a test like that shouldn't take more than an hour or two.  I did give candidates a very strict time limit to complete it ("call me when you are ready"), can get out of hand if there is none.

Comment: @HansPassant sounds like "get out of hand" is exactly the case here. OP's describes 16 hours of work assigned. That's a bit more than just a "test" for applicants.

Comment: I don't actually know what the common practice might be, just one I came up with myself.  16 hours is pretty unreasonable unless it includes sleep time.  And unproductive, enough time to post the question(s) at SO :)  The "call me when you are ready" worked *very* well.

Comment: Actually, the employer set a time frame of 6 days. Which makes it obvious that he knew there was a good deal of work involved, but I did it in a couple of days anyway. @Juice normally employers end up contacting me outside of the site by directly emailing me at the email in my CV. I suppose that was a bad practice of mine!

Comment: @SeldomNeedy "16 hours spent" doesn't necessarily say anything. I once spent three days on an example app like this; not because it was hard, but because I was experimenting with some new stuff (if you're writing meaningless code you might as well learn a thing or two)... Also, and I have no idea if this is the case, the OP may just not be a very fast programmer. I've seen people spend a week on what I could do in a day... :-/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - Granted. However, OP implies that this was effort which the company would be able to use _for its own gain_, not just an some involved takehome test. At best, the company is discourteous for not getting back to applicants who put up with the homework. At worst, the company is knowingly being exploitative.

Comment: Contracts, contracts, contracts. Your subsequent power to make legal threats can then be surprisingly effective, likely without you having to actually spend time or money on a lawyer.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Any issue you have with an employer can be reported to careers@stackoverflow.com

As to whether or not we find this acceptable, it's really hard for us to side with one or the other without knowing the scope of the work and hearing from the employer. We're always here to look into issues like this, but there's no absolute yes or nor regarding a situation like this.

Comment: I sent the email but didn't hear back from so careers. I just want to make the place better and hope you put the employer on your sights in case this happens again.

Answer (score 39):

The real answer is not to do anything for a prospective employer on your time without pay for that work. Asking you to do anything on your own time is a huge red flag.  First because if they aren't asking you to do it in an interview setting then they aren't investing anything into the work themselves-  they aren't serious.

Secondly-  my time is valuable, I'd rather spend it with family, on hobbies, or on my own projects.  There is no reason to give any employer your time for free.  Asking you to do so shows a huge lack of respect.

Third because they're idiots-  if you're doing it at home they have 0 proof that you actually did the work.  I've been asked by mediocre former coworkers to do it for them far too many times to ever trust work done when I can't see an interviewee.  If they do, then those mediocre employees will make the majority of your coworkers.

Comment: I agree, I should have not accepted the tasks in the first place.

Comment: Maybe that's the case where you live but I would be out of a job if I did not take those tests. Virtually all the companies I applied to (well-known ones included) asked for some kind of code challenge homework that takes about 8-10 hours of work.

Comment: Well, 8 hours and 2 days full time is not really the same (even if I think 8 hours is already a lot for this kind of test, maybe the exercice is badly prepared by the employer but there is quicker ways to check for competences without burning out the candidate that surely have other tests to do)

Comment: @Anyonymous2324 I wouldn't work for a company this silly. You can't properly judge a persons ability by a coding challenge, only wether or not they're a blatant fraud, and 20 minutes or an hour on site suffice for that.

Comment: @Magisch What I'm saying is that then you wouldn't work for any company where I live or nearby in the area that I work.

Comment: @Anyonymous2324 Fair enough then. Thankfully I live in germany and companys are clamoring to fnd IT personnel there so they can't afford to be this stupid if they want to fill a position.

Comment: I've lived in Seattle, silicon valley and Baltimore. I've been asked to do offsite challenges maybe once or twice out of dozens of interviews over 15 years. It really isn't that common, and we should refuse to do them to keep it that way

Comment: Unpaid 2-day assignments really sound like something that the industry should strive to stomp out - and SO careers should not be allowing employers on board who do this.

Comment: I think this is only acceptable if it's a coding challenge that the company has already worked out, and also that is just a toy project, i.e. Not something that the company actually needs.  This is the only type of assignments I've done, and I haven't had a problem with them. On the contrary, it's given me a chance to show where I can excel, and gotten me a job based on the quality and speed completed of a project.

Comment: If the task is thought through, I don't think it is a bad idea. I don't mind doing them. I often find them to be an interesting challenge and it gives me a good insight about what type of work I am expected to do. If the task seems boring, I just don't do it. That's true that anybody can do the exercise for me, but I have never seen that to be the entire interview; it was just one of the steps.

Comment: @Anyonymous2324 they require more than a day's worth of unpaid work as part of the interview process? Jesus...

Comment: Every company I've worked for has given me a test problem to solve as part of their interview process. But all have been done in their office with the one exception being a company that had me write some code in a shared google doc while on the phone with one of their engineers. I would be very skeptical of any company trying to get me to do work on my own time and I don't think that SO careers should tolerate that.

Comment: @canon 8-10 hours is not 2 days of work but I agree it is too much. I only took them because they were from companies I really wanted to work for, were obviously toy projects, and I was interviewed about my work afterwards. It was clearly part of the hiring process, not something meant to be used in production.

Comment: entirely possible the task is only intended to take maximum of a couple of hours and OP struggled to complete in reasonable timeframe

Comment: @DanielNugent Only if it's a short toy project. I'm all for "trust but verify" but when the project is 8+ hours you are beyond reasonable. 1-2 hours at max for a "toy" project, including any time to setup the environment.