# Are employers advertising on Jobs allowed to lie to an applicant?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

About two months back, I applied for a position that was located within my region, but it was remote only. I applied for the position and had a phone interview. I was under the impression that it went well, but I got a feeling something wasn't right. The company claimed to have several customers, but they didn't have a physical office space. They claimed to offer a payment services APO for large corporations. I was told I would be contacted back after they reviewed all the candidates.

About a day or so later, I received an email stating that they found a candidate better suited for the position. Since that time, I still see the same listing. Either the company is hiring more than one person for the same position, the response was a flat out lie or they forgot to take down the listing. If indeed it is a lie, should I be concerned?  Is the employer fishing for private information that can be used for other purposes?

Personally, I think an employer who lies to an applicant should be grounds for having their listing removed as it clearly establishes the employer as untrustworthy. If they are willing to lie to a candidate they are just as willing to lie about their intent.

Comment: Voted to migrate to the workplace SE. Well... oops, I can't. It is surely some trivial technical problem until the next deploy, isn't? ;-)

Comment: Some HR are non-confrontational when it comes to telling the applicant "you didn't pass". I'm not saying that you didn't though. Don't concern yourself too much about it; it's a good time to do self reflection and move on.

Comment: I find the title of this question prejudicial and misleading. To the extent that Stack Overflow has any influence over specific behaviors of employers at all, **of course those employers are not permitted to lie**. You don't really think Stack Overflow has written somewhere some sort of "sure, lie if you want to" policy, do you? Rather than calling the behavior you're asking about a "lie", how about you **stick to the facts as you know them with certainty**? And keep in mind that it's not Stack Overflow's job to adjudicate disputes between advertisers and advertisers' clients.

Comment: @PeterDuniho What is prejudicial and misleading.  You're the one prejudging my question. I asked if employers are allowed to lie to an applicant.  What more facts do do you want.  Did you bother to read my question? He made it clear that he hired someone else which is fine.

Comment: @KevinD. If he said that I am not qualified or I don't meet their needs, how is telling me that they hired someone else any better? Doesn't make sense. Also, what do you mean by self reflection?

Comment: Close voters: Questions about Jobs are on-topic for Meta.SO. Indeed, there's a "Feedback" link in the Jobs footer that leads here.

Comment: @user148298 Of course employers are allowed to "lie" to an applicant. Haven't you ever heard, "we'll be in touch" or 'thanks for coming in", after an interview? They may even say "We have other applicants to screen" and you're the only one to apply. Don't feel slighted, this should be water off your back. Move on and continue sending out applications!

Comment: @user148298 it's not any better, and yes it is lying - but doesn't mean their business is shady and/or they're fishing for personal information. I wouldn't concern myself with their motives if I were you; if you're really concerned - you can give them a ring. What I mean about self reflection is; try to determine what went wrong in the interview that made them decide to hire someone else, and how to avoid it in the next interview.

Answer (score 31):

"Thanks for applying, we hired somebody else" -> *posting is still up* is the same kind of lie as "I can't go out on a date with you Saturday because I have too much studying to do" -> *spotted at the movies with friends that night*.

Sure, it's a lie. It's hard to say that it's nefarious, though. It's just that person trying to avoid saying "you're rejected" to someone's face.

Are there better ways to handle this? Absolutely. Is it incredibly frustrating when it happens to you? Without question. Is it, in itself, a sign of a scam? I really don't think so.

That said, if you have other *concrete* points that you think add up to shady practices, you [can contact Stack Exchange about any problems you see on Jobs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318318/) by emailing careers@stackexchange.com

Comment: Sure, but would someone put that in writing?  Why leave the listing up for several months?

Comment: I would assume it's because they haven't found anyone they want to hire yet.

Comment: Saying you found someone better suited or saying that you're not a good fit has the same impact positive or negative. I once knew of a semi conman running a consultant company who would put out job adds and use them to get big contracts.  He never hired any of them. He also sold the resumes off to other agencies for a cut.

Comment: @user do you have any evidence other than that they told a white lie in their rejection letter that this is a shady enterprise?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Well, no office address listed. Website with no contact information. Apparently, they only sell to big corporations. What is the difference between a white lie and a normal lie?  Is there also a yellow lie too?  Is a white lie better than a yellow lie?

Comment: @user OK, those (to me) are signs to stay far, far away. The fact that they told you they’ve hired someone else, but didn’t, isn’t necessarily.  It could even be the truth - they might have had someone they were 100% sure they would hire, but something came up in the last second... unlikely, but possible. Either way, with all this combined, it’s never a mistake to share your gut feeling with the Jobs team and ask them to look into it.

Comment: The position might have a high rate of turnover. In that case, they are not being dishonest by keeping the post active, just cynical. Still not a great sign, and they should take it down to stop wasting people's time.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No, we would never condone an employer lying to candidates such as yourself.

However, it is very difficult for us to police and enforce honesty in communication between an employer and prospective candidates. Especially when we are not privy to the hiring practices and reasoning behind a given employer's decision to progress a candidate through their hiring process or not.

We can reach out to the company if you flag the job and we agree that something looks off or a pattern emerges.

In general, most companies are aware that the candidate experience is important and will do their best to act in good faith. If they're really bad, we'll refund their money and keep them out of the community.