# How to report company on SO Jobs that no longer exists?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, stack-overflow-jobs

In Stack Overflow Jobs, there are a number of companies that no longer exist (examples: [bitHound](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/bithound) and [Boltmade](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/boltmade)).

Is there a way to report these companies so they no longer appear in the search results? I know that there is the "Dismiss company" button, but I was hoping to help others by improving the data quality.

If not, I feel that this would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 64):

The best thing You can do is to write an email at **careers@stackoverflow.com** and explain the situation.

It's been [advised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332052/4241435) [in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318318/4241435) [the](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333176/4241435) [past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319034/4241435) so I'm sure they will handle it.

Comment: Not sure why this is receiving downvotes.

Comment: Maybe the downvotes are because people think there should be a better system in place to handle this?  Not that that's Skipper's fault for pointing out the only option of course, but it's the only reason I can think of as to why someone wouldn't like this answer.

Comment: Seems like we should add our generic answer into the tag excerpt.

Comment: If the answer is to write an email your process is broken.

Comment: @RyanRentfro That may well be but the answer is still pointing out what the current system *is*, as such there is nothing wrong with the *answer*.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I think Ryan is pointing out the SO's broken process

Comment: Skipper could add that it would be way better if there were another way to do this. That might avoid future downvotes.

Comment: Surely the downvotes are because there aren't hyperlinks behind *every* word on the last line!

Comment: RE downvotes: Downvoting on Meta isn't really saying "your answer is stupid and wrong"; it's more like "I prefer we do it the other way". -- see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites